# rdlc report - ‘A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source’ error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, reporting, rdlc

In my **ASP.Net Web pages** project I have created a new Web page and I dragged a script manager control onto it, then I created a new **rdlc report** using the wizard and configured the dataset (to show 3 fields of **Products table**: ProductName, quatityPerUnit, Price) which begun to retrieve data.

At the following step, I inserted a new Reportviewer and bound it to the previously created report, then again I verified that the data is retrieved by opening the dataset1.xsd file and clicking on preview data.

and this is my web page body code:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
            <LocalReport ReportPath="Reports\MyRdlcReport.rdlc">
                <DataSources>
                    <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="dsProducts" />
                </DataSources>
            </LocalReport>
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="WebApplication1.dsProductsTableAdapters.ProductsTableAdapter">

        </asp:ObjectDataSource>        
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

But When I run the project, I get the next error: **A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source ‘dataSource1’**, I have tried to find a similar case on the net but succeeded to find nothing, any help please ?

Comment: Is your request to migrate the reports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the cause, it was a non corresponding Tablix data set name property. I had to rename it from dataSet1 to dsProducts.

Answer (score 5):

You must realize the last step who is `defining  of datasource`

link : http://ruchitech.blogspot.fr/2012/07/how-to-create-rdlc-report-in-c.html

Note : see Choose Data Source

[image]

Comment: The datasource is already defined for the Report, and the report is already assigned to the report viewer, I've seen your link and I think all is done as shown in it ...

Comment: Visualize your code behind and check that this line exist : rdlc.DataSource = ....

Comment: Thank you for this.  I missed the step under that screenshot of Choose Data Source.  I thought that since I defined it in the RDLC designer, that it was finished.  After choosing the data sources, rebinding them

Answer (score 0):

```
// ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(Student);
```

In pageload make sure the above clear function for `ReportViewer` is made as comment or deleted to avoid the `Data source` instance has not be supplied error.

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio 13 offers an elegant solution to handle parameters in a sql server stored procedure:

ReportViewer
Steps To Create A Web Report using the Web version of the reportviewer

1. Create Webform using  Website/Add New Item
2. Drag ReportViewer on Webpage
3. Choose create new report (rdlc)
4. Select datasource for the report (be sure to rename before saving)
5. Use report generator to place fields on the report.
6. Save the report then rename default of report1.rdlc to the name desired
7. Move report and webpage to desired directory
8. Go to webpage reportviewer tasks and select the report.
9. Then choose data source (Parameters for the report can be added in the datasource)

Select New data source or the report will give an error:

A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source’

10. A new screen will appear showing various data sources.  Normally choose SQL data
11. Choose specify custom SLQ statement then hit NEXT
12. Choose stored procedure or choose SLQ statement and use the query builder.  Choosing stored procedure will allow the user to pick controls for the parameters of the stored procedure.  The wizard will then properly configure the web code thus eliminating any need for entering vb code such as below:

> ```
> Protected Sub ReportViewer1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ReportViewer1.Load
>     Dim Parm As New ReportParameter("BillingReportParm1", Profile.TherapistNo)
>     ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(Parm)
>     ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
> End Sub
> ```

13. An Example of the finished HTML code is shown below:

```html
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpMC" Runat="Server">
 <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Height="383px" Width="721px">
  <LocalReport ReportPath="Reports\BillingPendingRpt.rdlc">
   <DataSources>
    <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="SqlDataPendRpt" Name="BillingPendingRptDataSet" />
   </DataSources>
  </LocalReport>
 </rsweb:ReportViewer>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataPendRpt" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MMBDataConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="sp_WorkHour_Rpt" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
  <SelectParameters>
   <asp:ProfileParameter Name="Therapist" PropertyName="TherapistNo" Type="String" />
  </SelectParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```